# JPA join issue, not getting values from 'many' entity class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to join two entity classes by either using the @ManytoOne annotation (which as I understand the correct way) or Join in the query builder (throws error).

Here's the first entity class (the 'Many'):

```
public class PlanTactic implements Persistable<Integer>
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 5283865222214446581L;

@Id
@Column(name="TacticId")
private Integer id;

@Column(name="StartDate")
private Date startDate;

@Column(name="EndDate")
private Date endDate;
```

Here's the second entity class (the 'one'):

```
@ManyToOne(optional=false,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name="TacticId",referencedColumnName="TacticId",insertable=false,updatable=false)} )
private PlanTactic planTactic;
```

And here is the query in the repository class:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<PlanTacticDetail> q =   builder.createQuery(PlanTacticDetail.class);
Root<PlanTacticDetail> c = q.from(PlanTacticDetail.class);
//Root<PlanTactic> p = q.from(PlanTactic.class);
//q.multiselect(c,p.get("usingTargetList"));
q.where(c.get("month").in(months));
return em.createQuery(q).getResultList();
```

If i uncomment the lines above, I will get an error, this works only it shows me in the JSON only the second class (the 'one') no members from the 'many' class are coming up.

Thanks.

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: `builder.createQuery(PlanTacticDetail.class).from(PlanTactic.class)` Does that work!? What do you want to return?

Comment: List of the class PlanTacticDetails, but I need the member PlanTactic that has the @ManyToOne annotation to be generated too

Comment: If you return the resultlist with `PlanTacticDetails ptd`. You can just `ptd.getPlanTactic()` to get the PlanTactic member?

Comment: But I have a member in that class called PlanTactic, it's not being populated in the JSON output

Comment: So you want PlanTactic property to be loaded, when you query the list of PlanTacticDetails? If so, what you want to achieve is a join fetch. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

In JPA, ManyToOne associations are eagerly loaded by default. However, I assume the provider you are using is Hibernate. Somehow Hibernate will always load any object using a lazy fetch.

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<PlanTacticDetail> q = builder.createQuery(PlanTacticDetail.class);
Root<PlanTacticDetail> ptd = q.from(PlanTacticDetail.class);
ptd.fetch("planTactic");
```

Comment: For now I added a @Transient member and used that in a constructor, seems to work.